# Copy the doxygen of the initial value of a static variable to the \file block

Tags: variables, doxygen

I am trying to copy the doxygen of the initial value of a static variable to the top of my code in the \file block. That is, in something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

/*! \file Test.cxx
 * This is my program.
 * \copydetails HelpText
 */

/*! \var
 * This is my static string.
 */
static std::string HelpText = "Calculate the average magnitude of the vectors in a vector image.\n\n\
    Usage:\n\
    -in InputVectorImageFileName\n";

int main()
{

  return 0;
}
```

I would want the "Usage" string to appear in the main file documentation. As you can see I tried \copydoc but it only seems to copy the comment above the static variable, not the initial value. Note that the initial value appears properly in the variable's documentation.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar issue, in that I want to copy the complete documentation of an object into a summary/header document file rather than just link to it.  If that file is set in Example Path you can copy the whole file or a snippit from it, but this is not practical for most cases as making it an example file will keep it from being documented as a code file.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your [MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_max_initializer_lines) config in your doxyfile is either 0 or too small. Just give it a sensible value.

Comment: If MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES was too small, then the initial value would not appear at all, right? It does appear, just not in the second place :)

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped pointed me in the right direction to resolve my Doxygen issue.